# How to get IP of Heroku server, where is placed my app?

Tags: ruby, heroku, ip

I am trying to get IP address of server, where is running my app. In PHP exists the function called `GetHostByName()` (or something like that), what is the alternative for Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this (no shell required):

```
require 'socket'
def local_ip
  orig, Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup, true  # turn off reverse DNS resolution temporarily
  UDPSocket.open do |s|
    s.connect '64.233.187.99', 1
    s.addr.last
  end
ensure
  Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = orig
end
```

Output:

```
# irb:0> local_ip
# => "192.168.0.1"
```

I use this function, but credit goes to: http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/get-your-local-ip-address/

Comment: Please keep in mind this will change frequently as your app moves around. At least once a day, and on every release.